# Error compiling Week01

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I'm on commit: `41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a` of the `plutus-apps` repo (I've also tried `7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd`, doesn't seem to make a difference).

When running `cabal build` from `plutus-pioneers-program/code/week01`, I eventually run into this error:

```
Failed to build plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0.
Build log (
    /home/me/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.4/plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0-9c412f3bdd63445e3f9183c31cb9e0b26d503f4e4d00f925b065e9d46a4950e8.log
):
Configuring library for plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0..
Building library for plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0..
[ 1 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Error ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Error.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Error.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Error.dyn_o )
[ 2 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.PIRTypes ( src/PlutusTx/PIRTypes.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/PIRTypes.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/PIRTypes.dyn_o )
[ 3 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.PLCTypes ( src/PlutusTx/PLCTypes.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/PLCTypes.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/PLCTypes.dyn_o )
[ 4 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Types ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Types.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Types.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Types.dyn_o )
[ 5 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Utils ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Utils.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Utils.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Utils.dyn_o )
[ 6 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Type[boot] ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.hs-boot, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.o-boot, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.dyn_o )
[ 7 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Laziness ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Laziness.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Laziness.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Laziness.dyn_o )
[ 8 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Kind ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Kind.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Kind.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Kind.dyn_o )
[ 9 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Names ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Names.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Names.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Names.dyn_o )
[10 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Builtins ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Builtins.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Builtins.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Builtins.dyn_o )
[11 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Binders ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Binders.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Binders.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Binders.dyn_o )
[12 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Type ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Type.dyn_o )
[13 of 14] Compiling PlutusTx.Compiler.Expr ( src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Expr.hs, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Expr.o, dist/build/PlutusTx/Compiler/Expr.dyn_o )

src/PlutusTx/Compiler/Expr.hs:775:41: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘GHC.GenTickish’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘GHC.Tickish’ (imported from GhcPlugins),
      ‘GHC.Tickish’ (imported from CoreSyn)
    Neither ‘Class’, ‘CoreSyn’, ‘CostCentre’, ‘FV’, ‘GhcPlugins’,
            ‘MkId’ nor ‘PrelNames’ exports ‘GenTickish’.
    |
775 | getSourceSpan :: Maybe GHC.ModBreaks -> GHC.GenTickish pass -> Maybe GHC.RealSrcSpan
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build plutus-tx-plugin-0.1.0.0 (which is required by
plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for details.
```

Any idea how to workaround this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue, restarting the machine doesn't help as suggested above

Answer (score 0):

What version og GHC are you using. You should be using at least `ghc-8.10.4` but preferably `ghc-8.10.7`. You should not be using anything later than `8.10.7`.

Comment: I'm using 8.10.4

Comment: yeah still seeing the issue with 8.10.7

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error while running cabal build for the first time. Not sure if my process is what resolved it for me, but it was able to build.

Restart console and make sure nix binary caches are correct,

```
#> . /home/yourusernamehere/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh
cd plutus-apps
nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
```

Open new session, again verify binary caches,

```
#> . /home/yourusernamehere/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh,  
cd plutus-apps
nix-shell
cd path/to/plutus-pioneers-program/code/week01
cabal build
```